# How to do a calculation only at some rows of my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe with only two columns and 20 rows, where all values from the first column are equal to 10, and all values from the second row are random percentage numbers.

Now, I want to multiply the first column with the percentage values of the second column +1, but only at some intervals, and copy the last value to the next row.

E.g. I want to do this multiplication operation from row 5 to 10.

The problem Is that I don't know to start and end the calculation in arbitrary spots based on the df's index.

Example input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(20, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['A'] = 10
df['B'] = df['B'] /100
```

Which produces:

```
      A     B
0   10  0.07
1   10  0.02
2   10  0.05
3   10  0.00
4   10  0.01
5   10  0.09
6   10  0.00
7   10  0.02
8   10  0.03
9   10  0.05
10  10  0.05
11  10  0.03
12  10  0.01
13  10  0.09
14  10  0.06
15  10  0.07
16  10  0.01
17  10  0.01
18  10  0.01
19  10  0.07
```

An output I would like to get, is where the first row go thorugh a comulative multiplication only at sow rows, like this:

```
      C       B
0   10     0.07
1   10     0.02
2   10     0.05
3   10     0.00
4   10     0.01
5   10,9   0.09
6   10,9   0.00
7   11,11  0.02
8   11,45  0.03
9   12,02  0.05
10  12,62  0.05
11  12,62  0.03
12  12,62  0.01
13  12,62  0.09
14  12,62  0.06
15  12,62  0.07
16  12,62  0.01
17  12,62  0.01
18  12,62  0.01
19  12,62  0.07
```

Thank you!

Comment: please provide a sample of the input data you'd like to use and what you would expect as output, as your question is currently difficult to answer when we don't truly know what you want. And hey, if it suits you throw some code in there you've tried as well!

Comment: I've added some example data. Unfortunately, I don't have any attempt worth sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the recursive product you can do the following:

```
start = 5
end = 10

df['C'] = ((1+df.B)[start:end+1].cumprod().reindex(df.index[:end+1]).fillna(1)*df.A).ffill()
```

#### Output:

```
     A     B          C
0   10  0.07  10.000000
1   10  0.02  10.000000
2   10  0.05  10.000000
3   10  0.00  10.000000
4   10  0.01  10.000000
5   10  0.09  10.900000
6   10  0.00  10.900000
7   10  0.02  11.118000
8   10  0.03  11.451540
9   10  0.05  12.024117
10  10  0.05  12.625323
11  10  0.03  12.625323
12  10  0.01  12.625323
13  10  0.09  12.625323
14  10  0.06  12.625323
15  10  0.07  12.625323
16  10  0.01  12.625323
17  10  0.01  12.625323
18  10  0.01  12.625323
19  10  0.07  12.625323
```

---

#### Explanation:

Calculate the cumulative product of `(1 + df.B)`, which is the factor to mulitply by `df.A` to obtain the recursive product. Do this only over the range specified. `reindex` and fill the the rows before `start` with 1, so the value remains constant before this range.

Multiply by `df.A` to get the actual value, forward filling values after the range you specify.

Comment: This's exactly it! It works perfectly when using more than one range.